# Set date when a cell has specific text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that will write the date and time to column 14 the moment a cell in column 4 has the text "Assign". The problem I'm facing now is that column 14 won't change when I don't directly put "Assign" in column 4.

For example: I tell spreadsheets column 4 cell 4 =I4  and I have the text "Assign" in I4, column 14 won't display the current date time.

The moment I manually make column 4 cell 4 "Assign" Column 14 will display the date time.

The script works onEdit, may this be the problem? I am new to Google Apps Script.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh =  e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var val = e.range.getValue();

  //check if sheet is 'Blad1', column edited is 'C' & value is 'assign'
  if (sh.getSheetName() === 'Blad1' && col === 4 && val === 'Assign') {
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    var tz = e.source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'dd-MM-yyyy     hh:mm:ss');

    //set date in column 14 for same row
    sh.getRange(row, 14).setValue(date);

  }
}
```

The script only works when I directly put the text in column 4. I want the script to work whenever a cell in column 4 changes to "Assign".

P.S. Spreadsheet will get new data from a program called app sheet. When app sheet changes column 4 to "Assign" I need to show current time.

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation which is excerpted here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/119684/diference-between-onedit-or-onchange-trigger  You might be particularly interested in this bullet: "Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. For example, calling `Range.setValue()` to edit a cell does not cause the spreadsheet's onEdit trigger to run."

Comment: uhmm oke. in your link i only read what installable triggers cant do. But is there an other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This script will only perform `setValue()` if it is column 4 being updated, that's one of the things the `if` statement checks specifically:

```
if (sh.getSheetName() === 'Blad1' && col === 4 && val === 'Assign') {
```

If you want this to run every time the sheet is edited and `val === 'Assign'`, all you have to do is remove the column check from the `if` statement and define `val` using `getRange()` rather than the event object `e.range`.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var val = sh.getRange(row, 4).getValue();

  //check if sheet is 'Blad1' & value is 'Assign'
  if (sh.getSheetName() === 'Blad1' && val === 'Assign') {
    var tz = e.source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'dd-MM-yyyy     hh:mm:ss');

    //set date in column 14 for same row
    sh.getRange(row, 14).setValue(date);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes i believe this works!! Tomorrow i can test with the app sheet applictation. Much appriciated!

Comment: I tried it in App sheet and it dont work. The script will not see the changes made by app script as an edit..

Comment: If you're already running a script for setting the value for 'Assign' why not just include the timestamp as part of that script instead of having this separate script for it?

Comment: I am using app sheet. But when app sheet changes the value in a cell spreadsheet dont sees it as an edit so the script wont trigger.